# Zend - cannot find PHPUnit/framework.php

Tags: php, phpunit

I am running OSX Lion with an installation of XAMPP.  Setting up PEAR with XAMPP has proven to be difficult, but I got it work and installed PHPUnit.  When I look in the XAMPP pear directory I see a folder called 'PHPUnit', and when I look in that folder, I see the following files:

```
Assert.php
RepeatedTest.php
TestCase.php
TestFailure.php
TestResult.php
GUI
Skeleton.php
TestDecorator.php
TestListener.php
TestSuite.php
```

When I run `zf create project myproject`, I get the following message:

```
Warning: require_once(PHPUnit/Framework.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/frankie/Websites/Libraries/ZendFramework-1.11.10/library/Zend/Test/PHPUnit/ControllerTestCase.php on line 29
```

I have no idea where to get this Framework.php file or how to fix this.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zend Framework requires you to run `PHPUnit 3.5.x` and I assume you have installed `PHPUnit 3.6.x` from pear.

Check out the guide on how to [**`downgrade-phpunit-3-6-to-3-5-15`**](http://dustyreagan.com/downgrade-phpunit-3-6-to-3-5-15/) to fix your issue when running the ZF1 tests

Comment: I had to change the order of command execution in this guid because of the dependencies. Got the following error:
phpunit/PHPUnit (version >= 3.6.0) can be optionally used by installed package "phing/phing"
phpunit/PHPUnit (version >= 3.6.0) is required by installed package "phpunit/PHPUnit_Story"
phpunit/PHPUnit (version >= 3.7.0) is required by installed package "phpunit/PHPUnit_Selenium"
phpunit/PHPUnit cannot be uninstalled, other installed packages depend on this package
So I uninstalled the packages first and the PHPUnit itself.

Answer (score 1):

Check your bootstrap.php and disable fallback autoloader:
`Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance()->setFallbackAutoloader(false);`

Answer (score 0):

I also had to uninstall phing and replace it by an older version:

```
sudo pear uninstall phing/phing
sudo pear install phing/phing-2.3.3
```